# maven release:prepare junit

Tags: maven, junit, maven-plugin

I have a need to only run a specific jUnit when the `mvn release:prepare` is executed.  I don't want this to run under mvn install or any other goal as this jUnit is designed to see if the developer has executed a database activity first.

Is there any way to either have the junit know, by parameter(?), that the process under execution is `release:prepare`?

Or, is there a way to define within the *pom.xml* that this jUnit only runs on that goal?

I've been doing some searching on this and I cannot seem to find a solution as I'm not that good at maven as of yet.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done exactly what you want but the key is to use the `<executions>` section under the SureFire :

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      ... exclude the test from normal execution ...
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>release-phase</id>
        <phase>release-prepare</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          ... fill this in to include the tests you want ...
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
 <plugin>
```

You will also want to exclude that test in the normal `<configuration>` section.

There is some related information [HERE](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/maven/maven-integration-test)

Comment: I guess I was on the right track!  :)  I was starting to build this but didn't know how to complete it or if it would even work.  Thanks so much for this!!!

Comment: This answer as written will not work. See my answer for a more detailed explanation, but TL;DR there is no `release-prepare` phase

Comment: @StephenConnolly Hmmmm. No phases in release-prepare. I figured `release-prepare` wasn't right (note disclaimer above) but that there was some phase unique to release:prepare it could hang on. I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Others are close... but no cigar.

When Maven runs a release, there are no special phases for the release process. What you want to do is add a profile that is configured to include the test you want, e.g.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>release-preflight-checks</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>release-preflight-checks</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                .. include your test here
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you need to configure surefire by default to not execute your preflight check

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        .. exclude your test here
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And then finally, you need to tell Maven that this profile should be active only during `release:prepare`'s forked execution

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        ...
        <preparationGoals>clean verify -P+release-preflight-checks</preparationGoals>
        ...
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: it is vitally important to have the `+` in front of the profile name so that you are adding the profile to the list of active profiles otherwise your `release:prepare` step will not be validating that the build works with the release profile active and you can have a subsequent `release:perform` fail.

Note: A less complex route would be to just put the surefire configuration into the release profile that you are using (by default that has the id of `release` but that is more error prone as you could change that via the parent pom - e.g. if you decide to push your project to central, the sonatype-oss-parent changes the release profile to `sonatype-release` - and then you won't see the build being failed as the test would not be executed until you change your pom to match new the release profile's id... using the `-P+release-preflight-checks` ensures that the profile is *always* active for `release:prepare` and additionally has the benefit of meeting the requesters original requirement completely - i.e. only runs for `release:prepare` and doesn't run for `release:perform` which would be the case if the execution was added to the release profile)

Comment: I wonder if OP is trying to do this to make sure the human doing the release has done something to the database related to release and has used a junit test, not to test the code, but to check that protocol has been followed. I wonder, if that's the case, if it might be easier to write it as a plugin based variation. Sort of a `maven-is-release-ok-plugin` thingy.

Comment: Well since the plugin will most likely not be hosted by the Apache Maven project itself, it had better be named `is-release-ok-maven-plugin` or I will be forced to send a cease and desist letter on behalf of the PMC :-(

Comment: Please refer to the "sort of" in the previous message and call off the lawyers. :)

Comment: Just trying to correct a bad habit that people have which causes a pile of pain for those of us on the PMC... once we have been made aware of an infringing usage we have to defend our mark... it was hard enough to get the `____-maven-plugin` exemption!